# Ignore spaces in the Elasticsearch 6.5 querystring query

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using the querystring query to filter documents in the ElasticSearch 6.5 cluster. The documents I need to find contain field with some command line arguments (with special characters including spaces and double quotes).

For instance:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /tn "Microsoft\Office\Office Feature Updates Logon" /XML "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ClickToRun\{9AC08E99-230B-47e8-9721-4577B7F124EA}\Microsoft_Office_Office Feature Updates Logon.xml"
```

And I don't know how to query this exact string without having to escape every space and other special characters [described](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) in the documentation.

I am able to find it with the query like this (all the necessary escaping for the json format is skipped for the convenience):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
        "query_string": {"query": "field:schtasks.exe\ \/create*"}
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

And it works though it is very difficult for the user which input is passed directly to the querystring parameter.

I want a way to ignore spaces in the provided search query and query it as is, possibly even without escaping other special characters. One intuitive solution would be wrapping the query in double quotes:

```
"query_string": {"query": "field:\"schtasks.exe /create*\""}
```

But it doesn't work.

Update:
I have the following mapping for the `field`:

```
...
"field": 
{
  "type": "keyword",
  "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
},
...
```

Comment: You've mentioned your instance as `schtasks.exe /Create /tn "Microsoft\Office\Office Feature Updates Logon" /XML "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\ClickToRun\{9AC08E99-230B-47e8-9721-4577B7F124EA}\Microsoft_Office_Office Feature Updates Logon.xml"`  How did you ingest this value in Elasticsearch. Could you share a sample document which you have ingested the above value as in in ES?